# Is "docker logs container-id | tail -10" a valid command?

Tags: docker, tail

I'm running the command `docker logs <container-id> | tail -10` and still, docker shows the entire log history. I know `docker logs --tail 10 <container-id>` is a valid command and serves the purpose. But, why doesn't the former command works as it does in case of a file?

Comment: Please don't write titles that one needs to click through to understand what the "this" that your question is actually about *is*. I've edited to be more explicit.

Comment: That said -- check whether the logs are going to stderr rather than stdout; that would explain them bypassing `tail`.

Comment: (BTW, note that piping into `tail` is an O(n) operation -- it needs to read through *n* other lines, to get to the last 10, because a FIFO -- and UNIX pipes are FIFOs -- can only be read front-to-back; by contrast, `tail -n -10 somefile`, given a real file, is effectively constant-time; it just jumps straight to the end of the file, backs up 8KB, reads that, and then only needs to search through that chunk to find the last 10 lines... or back up further if your lines are crazy long).

Comment: (...consequently, `cat anything | tail` is ridiculously slow for non-tiny values of *anything*, whereas `tail anything` is typically able to be very fast).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got your point that the command is a costly operation, but it still should've worked, right?

Comment: **If** it was writing to stdout, yes. As I instructed, in my very second comment: Go validate that assumption. That might look like running `docker logs some-container >logs.out 2>logs.err`, and checking to see if the content is in the `.out` file or the `.err` file.

Comment: I did what you said. My logs.out file came out to be totally empty but logs.err not. This could only mean that all the logs were redirected to stderr, but I was pretty sure that not all logs were errors, so I compared the size of logs.err and the actual log file which docker had saved. Size of the files was 4.3M and 6.7M. Where are the rest of the logs going?

Comment: To answer your question ("where are the rest of the logs going?"), we'd need a reproducer. If your Docker container is `RUN`ning a program that redirects its stdout to a file, where that other content is going is, well, stdout. Either way, you need to look into that specific container and the software it's running.

Comment: BTW, note that stderr isn't for *errors* specifically; all diagnostic and informational output belongs there. (That said, for a program that's designed to retrieve logs, I'd call those logs themselves the standard output, and information about *the process of retrieving those logs* the diagnostic output).

Comment: The docker json logfiles in the docker container directory will have overhead (json fields track various bits of metadata for each line, including which output stream and timestamp), they will always be larger than the actual logs from your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your everything your program writes to either stdout or stderr to go through the pipeline to `tail`, redirect stderr to stdout:

```
docker logs "$container_id" 2>&1 | tail -10
```

Comment: @Konrad, as `<` and `>` are syntactically meaningful in bash, better to pick a different placeholder form. And better to put the redirections at the front or end -- wider compatibility with other shells than putting them in the middle, even though bash allows it.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying @Charles. I tested the redirections at the front and it worked, so that's why I put it there. Haven't analyzed "the best" position for it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

in case someone may want to tail -f docker logs

here you may try this:

```
docker logs -f --tail 0 "$container_id"
```